# Pre-populate a form from a link

Tags: php

Apologies if this question has already been asked...

I need to the data that is entered in form1, to be sent to form2 through the URL, form2 to read the data from the URL, populate the fields of form2, submit, then redirect to a thanks page.

I was thinking of sending the information through GET in the URL.
I don't want form2 to be seen by the user, just form1 and then the thanks page if successful.

I did try this using the below method...

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<form method="POST" name="test" id="test" action="process.php">
<label for="fname">First name</label>
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" /><br />

<label for="lname">Last name</label>
<input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" /><br />

<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" /><br />

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

//Collect data set in the URL
if (isset($_POST['fname'])) { $fname = trim($_POST['fname']); }
if (isset($_POST['lname'])) { $lname = trim($_POST['lname']); }
if (isset($_POST['email'])) { $email = trim($_POST['email']); }

// Prepare web to lead link 
$url = 'success.php?fname='.$fname.'&lname='.$lname.'&email='.$email;

// GO!
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

**success.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

//Collect data set in the URL
if (isset($_GET['fname'])) { $fname = trim($_GET['fname']); }
if (isset($_GET['lname'])) { $lname = trim($_GET['lname']); }
if (isset($_GET['email'])) { $email = trim($_GET['email']); }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Form test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<label for="fname">First name</label>
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="<?php echo isset($fname); ?>" /><br />

<label for="lname">Last name</label>
<input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" value="<?php echo isset($lname); ?>" /><br />

<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php echo isset($email); ?>" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

index.php being form1, process.php collecting the data and submitting the form2, success.php being form2

Any suggestions?

Comment: try value="<?php echo $fname; ?> same for lname and email

Comment: user jquery form wizard. I hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form contents when submitted in index.php will be transferred to process.php using POST method and in process.php, it prepares the link and redirects the user to success.php using header() (instead of curl), and then in success.php, the form input fields are pre-populated by using `<?php if(isset($fname)) echo $var; ?>` (you were doing `<?php echo isset($fname); ?>` which will simply output 1 or 2 depending on the condition)

The changed code should look like this **(tested)**:

**process.php**:

```
<?php
session_start();

//Collect data set in the URL
if (isset($_POST['fname'])) {   $fname = trim($_POST['fname']); }
if (isset($_POST['lname'])) {   $lname = trim($_POST['lname']); }
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {   $email = trim($_POST['email']); }

// Prepare web to lead link 
$url = 'success.php?fname='.$fname.'&lname='.$lname.'&email='.$email;

// GO!
header("Location: $url");
?>
```

**success.php**:

```
<?php
session_start();

//Collect data set in the URL
if (isset($_GET['fname'])) { $fname = trim($_GET['fname']); }
if (isset($_GET['lname'])) { $lname = trim($_GET['lname']); }
if (isset($_GET['email'])) { $email = trim($_GET['email']); }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Form test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<h2> Submitted Form </h2>
<label for="fname">First name</label>
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="<?php if(isset($fname)) echo $fname; ?>" /><br />

<label for="lname">Last name</label>
<input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" value="<?php if(isset($lname)) echo $lname; ?>" /><br />

<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php if(isset($email)) echo $email; ?>" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: This looks like it could be a winner. You're correct, when testing, I was getting a 1 in the form fields as opposed to the actual value. I will test and let you know how I get on. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Just tested and it worked. I kept the cURL bit in though because I wanted the user to be taken to a thanks page after the info was submitted to the form. I just added in a header after the cURL was closed. Thanks for your help

Comment: Is there any scope for adding a checkbox into the mix? Or will this just complicate things? Just realised that there needs to be a checkbox

Answer (score 1):

You can send the data with POST and then save it to the SESSION, so it's available from any of your pages; the user will still be able to see the data but would require some more work by having to use the developer tools or Firebug.